# ¿Cómo puedo leer un archivo de texto que el usuario seleccione en Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Tengo una activity con dos botones, uno de seleccionar y otro de subir, lo que necesito es que el usuario mediante el botón de seleccionar se le abra el explorador de archivos por defecto y seleccione el archivo que necesita (Y me gustaría que sólo pudiera seleccionar archivos de texto), una vez seleccionado regrese a la activity donde tengo los botones y subir los datos del archivo a una base de datos sqlite. El archivo debe estar separado con "~" entre campos.

Este es mi código pero no se que hacer:

```
public void selecArchivo(View vista){
    int VALOR_RETORNO = 1;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Escoge el Archivo"), VALOR_RETORNO);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Asigna los parámetros correspondientes a tu `intent.setType()`

```
 intent.setType("text/*");
```

[Documentación intent.setType()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setType(java.lang.String))